# Extension “RANDR” missing on xvfb

Tags: 14.04, framebuffer, xvfb

**Ubuntu:**

```
$lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

**Xvfb:**

```
$ dpkg -s xvfb
Package: xvfb
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: x11
Installed-Size: 2140
Maintainer: Ubuntu X-SWAT <ubuntu-x@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: foreign
Source: xorg-server
Version: 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.7
Provides: xserver
```

**Current problem:**

Xvfb do not support RANDR extension, even if I add the flag:

```
+extension RANDR
```

If I run xdpyinfo, RANDR is not on the list. It's a missing feature or a bug.
I found a reference here with a patch: https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=823410

And looks like that in other distros like debian, there is already a testing build of Xvfb with support: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205509/running-firefox-in-xvfb-extension-randr-missing-on-display

I am trying to run a program throught Xvfb, and it returns the following error:

```
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99".
```

The program works if I run it via ssh/command line. The problem appears to be the the lack of support for "RANDR" in xvfb.

My question is: what is the easiest way to get xvfb with "RANDR" support in my system?

Answer (score 2):

This may be a problem with the package install for 14.0.4.  On 16.0.4:

```
$sudo apt-get install xvfb
$Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x24 > /dev/null &

$ xdpyinfo -display :99 | grep "number of extensions"  -A 25
number of extensions:    25
    BIG-REQUESTS
    Composite
    DAMAGE
    DOUBLE-BUFFER
    DPMS
    GLX
    Generic Event Extension
    MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
    MIT-SHM
    Present
    **** RANDR ****
    RECORD
    RENDER
    SECURITY
    SGI-GLX
    SHAPE
    SYNC
    X-Resource
    XC-MISC
    XFIXES
    XINERAMA
    XInputExtension
    XKEYBOARD
    XTEST
    XVideo
```